# What should my Nginx rewrite rules be for Rails with Passenger for page caching in a subdirectory?

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, rewrite, phusion-passenger

I'm using Nginx 0.7.64, Passenger 2.2.9, Rails 2.3.5.  I have my page caching directory set to /public/cache, and I'd like to be able to serve cached pages when requested over HTTP, but always hit the Rails app when requested over HTTPS.

The bulk of my config looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name website.com www.website.com;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
  root /home/deploy/website/current/public;
  passenger_enabled on;

  if (-f $document_root/cache/$request_filename.html) { 
    rewrite (.*) $document_root/cache/$1.html break;
  }
}

server {
  listen       443;
  server_name website.com www.website.com;
  root /home/deploy/website/current/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /home/deploy/website/shared/ssl/www.website.com.combined.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /home/deploy/website/shared/ssl/www.website.com.key;
}
```

I anticipate that when I request website.com/about, I should be served /public/cache/about.html, but instead I hit the Rails server (tailing the log shows it).

Thinking I might have an inappropriate slash (and not seeing `$document_root` in most examples), I've also tried all of the following variations, none of which work:

```
if (-f cache$request_filename.html) { 
  rewrite (.*) cache$1.html break;
}

if (-f /cache$request_filename.html) { 
  rewrite (.*) /cache$1.html break;
}

if (-f cache/$request_filename.html) { 
  rewrite (.*) cache/$1.html break;
}

if (-f /cache/$request_filename.html) { 
  rewrite (.*) /cache/$1.html break;
}
```

I've also thrown the `root`, `passenger_enabled`, and rewrite rules into a separate `location /` block, but that also does not work.  I've also reordered the statements so that `passenger_enabled` would come at the end.  I've also tried using `$uri`.  Clearly I'm misunderstanding something!

This is a little bit simplified, since I also have an XML api that is cached in places (presumably the rewrite rule will be the same except for the `.html` parts), as well as I'll need to serve `public/cache/index.html` when the root of `website.com` is requested.  I just want to get any single piece of it working. :)

Any help is appreciated!

**Update**

The conditional

```
if (-f $document_root/cache$request_uri.html)
```

Seems to work!  However, what I would think would be the rewrite does not work!  Trying

```
if (-f $document_root/cache$request_uri.html) {
  rewrite (.*) /cache$1.html break;
  break;
}
```

Rewrites the URL as `/cache/cache/about.html.html` and sends it to Rails, which promptly barfs.  It looks doubled, yes!  But if I rewrite to just `/cache$1` it sends `/cache/cache/about` to Rails, and `$1.html` sends `/about.html.html` to Rails, and just `$1` sends simply `/about` which goes to Rails and does not hit the cache.  Obviously this is not correct behavior  Is Nginx rewriting it and then Passenger is rewriting it, too?

Comment: here is manual http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html for converting apache rewrites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was found here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177979/nginx-rewrite-rules-with-passenger

The config ended up being:

```
# root
if (-f $document_root/cache/$uri/index.html) {
  rewrite (.*) /cache/$1/index.html break;
}

# pages like /about, cached with .html but accessed without
if (-f $document_root/cache/$uri.html) {
  rewrite (.*) /cache/$1.html break;
}

# pages like /api/v1/something.xml, cached as xml
if (-f $document_root/cache/$uri) {
  rewrite (.*) /cache/$1 break;
}
```

Comment: there is `try_files` directive for that

Comment: @SaveTheRbtz would you mind show the try_files way (and edit the answer) please?

Answer (score 1):

`try_files` version:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name website.com www.website.com;
  location / {
    root /home/deploy/website/current/public;
    try_files $uri /cache/$uri/index.html /cache/$uri.html /cache/$uri @passenger;
  }
  location @passenger {
    root /home/deploy/website/current/public;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    passenger_enabled on;
  }
}
```

note that it might or might not work with passenger. I'm sure it works with unicorn, mongrel, etc though.

Comment: This does not appear to work with Passenger as of 2.2.9.  Cached files are served appropriately, but uncached requests do not hit the Rails app.

Comment: (In a separate, much less important comment, static files like CSS and JS are accesses directly from $uri, so that needs added to the list.)

Comment: oh right, add it as the first. The main problem is there's no way to fallback to passenger. When using unicorn and co, the content of @passenger is the proxy_pass to backend.

Comment: or try adding root to location @passenger block.

    location @passenger {
      root /home/deploy/website/current/public;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
      passenger_enabled on;
    }